# Visual Studio Code extension for remote editing of Python source codes

Tags: ssh, source-code, editor, visual-studio-code

**Task**

I need a Visual Studio Code extension to edit Python source files `.py` (preferably more than one at the same time, ideally an entire VSCode workspace) on a single remote server, using the Visual Studio Code app installed on my client.

**Requirements**

1. (mandatory) I *don't want* to install VSCode on the remote server.  I can install code on the remote server if necessary, such as for example Python modules, but I would like to keep installations on the remote server to a minimum.
2. (mandatory) The extension *must be* stable and reliable. Configuring each one of these extensions is time-consuming, thus I don't want to spend the time to configure one, just to have it crash and/or lose connectivity every now and then.
3. (nice to have) The extension should be easy to configure. I'm not a Visual Studio Code wizard. However, I've been able to deal with non-trivial configurations before, thus this requirement is not mandatory.

**What I know already**

I know there are many extensions available in the [VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/), but I'm having difficulties choosing among them. Some seem to be very popular (good), but they allow only editing one file at a time (bad) such as [Remote VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode#overview). Some others allow editing multiple files, but they are occasionally unstable, such as [Remote Workspace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-remote-workspace)
. Then there are even more extensions such as [Remote FS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.remotefs)
 and [SSH FS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs#overview).

Can you help me choosing the extension which is better suited to my use case?

Comment: **Must** it be Visual Studio Code? The best Python IDE I know of is JetBrains' PyCharm, and the community edition is free, even for commercial use.

Comment: @Mawg it **must**. The free edition of PyCharm [doesn't support remote editing and debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html).

Comment: @Mawg well, actually other free solutions apart from VSCode could be ok, but 1) they must be able to run Python code, 2) they must be a modern IDE (no `vim`, `nano` or `emacs`). I mostly have experience with Sublime, VSC & PyCharm, thus I would have to learn another IDE, but if there is no decent VSCode solution, I'll bite.